# 14.04 php7 install - Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php'

Tags: ppa, php7

I want to install php 7 version on Ubuntu 14.04.

I run below command (root account).

```
# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

and result is.

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Actually I am in firewall env. so there's http_proxy variable setting.

```
# env | grep proxy
http_proxy=1.2.3.4:8080
https_proxy=1.2.3.4:8080
```

1.2.3.4 is an example, it will be correct.

And I don't know why and find out why, did strace command.

```
# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 strace -o strace.out add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

I can see many locale file error like below.

```
stat("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffdab3ee570) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo", 0x7ffdab3ee570) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

At last part of the output.

```
stat("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/software-properties.mo", 0x7ffe925eb460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/software-properties.mo", 0x7ffe925eb460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php'"..., 86) = 86
write(1, "\n", 1)
```

Is there a problem related with locale??
Or I guess network problem (because I am in office and my office can prohibit other IP).

Comment: add-apt-repository does need network access to proceed, since it has to acquire the PPA description. If you have problem accessing network that may be the reason. Can you access launchpad.net? I doubt it's related to locale, those strace messages just show that the program is trying to read translations of en_US.UTF-8.